# Simplifying lists in python?

Tags: python

I'm new to coding, and am wondering if there is a way to simplify this:

```
if "!" in name or "$" in name or "%" in name or "^" in name or "&" in name or "*" in name or "(" in name or ")" in name or "_" in name or "-" in name or "+" in name or "=" in name:
points = points + 1
```

Thank you

Comment: `if any(c in name for c in '!$%^'): ...`.  (I didn't type out all the characters for brevity)

Comment: @mgilson If you wanted brevity, you would've added those few chars instead of adding "(I didn't type out all the characters for brevity)" :-P

Comment: Here is a one-liner based on mgilson: `points += any(c in name for c in "!$%^&*()_-+=")`. This works because: If false: points += 0, True: Points +=1. Thanks to Stefan Pochmann too.

Comment: @StefanPochmann -- Ahh, but you forget the amount of time it takes to cross-reference to make sure that I got them all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex:

```
import re
if re.findall('[\!\$\%\^\&\*\_\-\+\=]', name):
   points += 1
```

Comment: You beat me to the answer. :)

Comment: @StefanPochmann please see my recent edit

Comment: Yeah, that works. But it's super ugly. There's really only a single character there that needs escaping (or putting it first or last). Also, why `findall` instead of `search`?

Comment: Sheesh, in plain old C days we had `strstr` for this kind of stuff. And it was *fun.*

Comment: @yacc Huh? `strstr` doesn't do what this is doing...

Comment: However, it was fun. :D

Answer (score 2):

```
chars = set("!$%^&*()_-+=")

if any((i in chars) for i in string):
  points += 1
```

Comment: Oops, was meant as a suggestion but became an edit. As int(True/False) evaluates to 1/0 you could go straight to adding the points. +1

Comment: `ctrl c - ctrl v` of @mgilson 's  comment and adding a redundant `()` around the boolean statement...

Comment: @jojo There's no tuple anywhere.

Comment: Deleted @AntonvBR 's edit, seems like a separate answer, rather then addition to mine

Comment: That's fine. It wasn't another answer but really just a way of adding the point in one line. int(boolean) evaluates to 0/1. Hence no if-statement needed. False: points += 0, True: Points +=1

Comment: @jojo Don't get it, that's basically what I suggested? :) Anyway.. let's move on!

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple function to achieve this.

```
def is_included(characters, sentence):
    for character in characters:
        if character in sentence:
            return True
    return False
```

As mgilson mention you can use `any` keyword too. However since you are new to programming I suggest you to learn the algorithms of keywords.

Comment: Upps it should be True and False my baf